# Класс Matrix оцените реализацию

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

Часто слышал про задачки, типо реализуйте класс для матриц, комплексных чисел и т.д. Вот, наконец-то, попробовал. Меня интересует мнение, хорошо ли он реализован? Может можно как-то по другому и куда собственно двигаться дальше? Можно ли как-то усложнить реализацию? И где можно найти задачи где нужно не только реализовывать алгоритмы (то есть сплошная математика), а еще и пользоваться возможностями языка (наследования, обобщения, обработка исключений и т.д.).

```
package matrix;

public class Matrix {

    private final int rows;
    private final int columns;
    private int[][] matrix;

    /****************** Constructors ******************/
    public Matrix() {
        this.rows    = 1;
        this.columns = 1;
        this.matrix  = new int[rows][columns];
    }

    public Matrix(int rows, int columns) throws MatrixException {

        if(rows <= 0 || columns <= 0) {
            throw new MatrixException("Заданы неверные размеры матрицы");
        }

        this.rows    = rows;
        this.columns = columns;
        this.matrix  = new int[rows][columns];
    }

    public Matrix(int size) throws MatrixException {
        if(size <= 0) {
            throw new MatrixException("Заданы неверные размеры матрицы");
        }

        this.rows = this.columns = size;
        this.matrix = new int[size][size];
    }

    public Matrix(int[][] matrix) {
        this.rows    = matrix.length;
        this.columns = matrix[0].length;
        this.matrix  = matrix;
    }
    /************************************************************************/

    public static final Matrix sum(Matrix matrix1, Matrix matrix2) throws MatrixException {

        if(!check(matrix1, matrix2, false)) {
            throw new MatrixException("Размеры матриц не совпадают");
        }
        else {

            int size;

            if(!matrix1.checkSquare()) {
                size = matrix1.rows > matrix1.columns ? matrix1.columns : matrix1.rows;
            }
            else {
                size = matrix1.rows;
            }

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix(size);

            for(int i = 0; i < matrix1.rows; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < matrix1.columns; j++) {
                    matrix.matrix[i][j] = matrix1.matrix[i][j] + matrix2.matrix[i][j];
                }
            }

            return matrix;
        }
    }

    public static final Matrix multiply(Matrix matrix1, Matrix matrix2) throws MatrixException {

        if(!check(matrix1, matrix2, true)) {
            throw new MatrixException("Размеры матриц не совпадают");
        }
        else {

            int size;
            int n;

            if(!matrix1.checkSquare()) {
                size = matrix1.rows > matrix1.columns ? matrix1.columns : matrix1.rows;
                n = matrix1.rows > matrix1.columns ? matrix1.rows : matrix1.columns;
            }
            else {
                size = matrix1.rows;
                n = matrix1.rows;
            }

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix(size);
            matrix.fill(0);

            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                        matrix.matrix[i][j] += matrix1.matrix[i][k]*matrix2.matrix[k][j];
                    }
                }
            }

            return matrix;
        }
    }

    public final void print() {

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
               System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public final void fill(int number) {

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private final static boolean check(Matrix matrix1, Matrix matrix2, boolean forMultiply) {
        if(forMultiply) {
            return ((matrix1.rows == matrix2.rows) && (matrix1.columns == matrix2.columns)) ||
                    (matrix1.columns == matrix2.rows);
        }
        else {
            return (matrix1.rows == matrix2.rows) && (matrix1.columns == matrix2.columns);
        }
    }

    public final boolean checkSquare() {
        return rows == columns;
    }
}

package matrix;

public class MatrixException extends Exception {

    private String cause;

    MatrixException(String cause) {
        this.cause = cause;
    }

    public String cause() {
        return this.cause;
    }
}
```

Comment: Мое чисто субъективное мнение - не надо хранить то, что можно вычислить - в java, насколько я помню, массив - объект и хранит уже в себе параметр size - хранить два дополнительных инта классно, но лично я бы этого делать не стал. Такое небольшое ИМХО.

Answer (score 1):

В целом код мне понравился, вот несколько моментов, которые я бы переделал (это моё субъективное мнение, для краткости я не стал добавлять в каждое предложение слова "Мне кажется, что ..."):

1. Рассмотрим метод `check`. Он принимает два параметра и булевый флаг, и в зависимости от флага выполняет два разных кода. Что если вы добавите к операциям сложения и умножения третью операцию? Как тогда будет определяться, какую из трёх проверок делать (не передавать же два флага)? Лучше разделить этот метод на два, `checkSum` и `checkMultiply`. Ещё лучше убрать эти методы (они всё равно используются только в методах `sum` и `multiply`) и занести код проверок внутрь методов `sum` и `multiply`, так код станет понятней.
2. Рассмотрим фрагмент кода в методе `sum`:

   ```
   int size;

   if (!matrix1.checkSquare()) {
       size = matrix1.rows > matrix1.columns ? matrix1.columns : matrix1.rows;
   } else {
       size = matrix1.rows;
   }
   ```

   начнём с этой строчки:

   ```
   size = matrix1.rows > matrix1.columns ? matrix1.columns : matrix1.rows;
   ```

   тут берётся минимум из `matrix1.columns` и `matrix1.rows`. Если переписать через [`Math.min`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-int-int-), получится лучше:

   ```
   if (!matrix1.checkSquare()) {
       size = Math.min(matrix1.rows, matrix1.columns);
   } else {
       size = matrix1.rows;
   }
   ```

   далее, подумаем, нужен ли нам вообще `if`? Если матрица квадратная, то `matrix1.rows == matrix1.columns` и вариант кода для неквадратной матрицы корректно обработает этот случай. Таким образом фрагмент можно сократить до

   ```
   int size = Math.min(matrix1.rows, matrix1.columns);
   ```
3. Далее, зачем нам вообще в методе `sum` было вычислять минимум из размерностей матриц? Если матрицы неквадратные, то где-то дальше по коду возникнет исключение `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Возможно вместо минимума должен вычисляться максимум, но это тоже не очень хорошо: почему суммой двух матриц должна обязательно быть квадратная матрица? ЛУчше если суммой двух матриц будет матрица такой же размерности. Поэтому я бы переписал метод вот так:

   ```
   public static final Matrix sum(Matrix matrix1, Matrix matrix2) throws MatrixException {
       if (matrix1.rows != matrix2.rows || matrix1.columns != matrix2.columns) {
           throw new MatrixException("Размеры матриц не совпадают");
       } else {
           Matrix matrix = new Matrix(matrix1.rows, matrix1.columns);
           for(int i = 0; i < matrix1.rows; i++) {
               for(int j = 0; j < matrix1.columns; j++) {
                   matrix.matrix[i][j] = matrix1.matrix[i][j] + matrix2.matrix[i][j];
               }
           }
           return matrix;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Метод `multiply` также всегда возвращает квадратную матрицу, стоит исправить, чтобы для матриц размера `n x m` и `m x k` возвращал матрицу `n x k`.
5. Рассмотрим метод `fill(int number)`:

   ```
   public final void fill(int number) {
       for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
           for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
               matrix[i][j] = 0;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   здесь небольшая опечатка, вместо заполнения матрицы числом `number` происходит заполнение матрицы нулями.
6. Метод `checkSquare` лучше назвать `isSquare`